# Organizing the build steps on AzureDevOps

Tags: azure-devops, build-pipeline, release

I am new on DevOps world and I am making my first build/release pipeline for a .net web application using Azure DevOps. On the picture bellow, I just add some build steps and create some tasks groups to avoid duplications on the builds (that are similar). I have the `Run on agent` that I called it as `Qa Agent Job`  which runs over the local build agent hosted on my build server (as a windows service).

My question is related with organization. I have some build steps here and I would like to organize it by sessions, for sample, Nuget Restore, Versioning, Build, Testing, Building services, Publishing artifacts etc. Is that a problem to organize it using the `Run on agent` item on build step? Should I lost any performance like "connecting on the server again" or "start a new process" or something like that?

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Do you want to run the tasks in many agents?

Comment: Well, we have an agent pool defined and inside this one we have 3 agents (windows services).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can separate the steps, especially as it would let you do divide the work among different agents. You can also leave them in a single agent if you wish.

The primary advantage I see is leveraging different pools for different sets of work.

With releases last I checked variable scope was limited (as of 2018) to the "phase".

I wouldn't necessarily worry about performance due to connections unless you've observed this issue and have more specific detail you can add.